# How to make multilingual website using Sails.js + Jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug, sails.js

I am new to Node.js Sails.js, Jade. Is there any example/tutorial of how to develop multilingual web site by using SAILS.JS+JADE

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sails ships with [i18n-node](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node) . your localization files can be found under ./config/locales/

in a freshly generated sails app you should be able to write

```
#{i18n('Hello')}
```

in your jade file an it gets properly translated to "Sup" (this is the value for the key "hello" in ./config/locales/en.js. sails ... or i18n for that matter chooses the locale based on the "accept-language" http header. if you send an request to the same page with the accept-language set to "es" you should be getting "Hola" instead of "Sup" (again ... this is the case for newly generated apps)

hope i could help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any tutorials so, my apologies, this is not a well focused answer. However rather than leaving this unanswered, this is what we do:

1. The code contains English text fragments so its easier to read.
2. Wrap these fragments in a call to a native language routine e.g. makeNative('Your name:')
3. makeNative is basically

   ```
   function makeNative(frag)
     var translations = {
       'fr': {
         "Your name:": "Votre nom",
         ...
       },
       'gr': {
       }
     };
     return translations[currLang][frag] || frag;
   }
   ```
4. You will soon find yourself using placeholders and will need a function to perform substitutions.

   ```
   "%1 foo foo %2 foo": "bar %2 bar %1 bar bar"
   ```
5. Then you need routines to handle (a) quantities (b) currencies (c) dates.
6. German requires about 30% more chars than English so bear that in mind during design.

Answer (score 0):

All of the following jade/translation syntax options worked for me:

```
h1 #{__("Welcome")}

h1=__("Welcome")

h1 #{i18n('Welcome')} 

h1=i18n("Welcome")
```

Caveats:

- Jade support must be enabled by installing the jade module:

  npm install jade --save
- The view engine must be set to "jade" (in config.views.js)
- Your template must be in proper jade format & have a .jade extension.